# POSIX usage standards for requiring at least one optional arg

Tags: command-line, options, documentation

So, I'm writing a CLI for an API, and I ran into a point where one of the commands `support` has two optional arguments, `id` and `fields`

I want to know how to show that these arguments are optional, BUT, you have to supply at least ONE of them, or even both. I'm not sure how to word the Google search, so I haven't been able to turn anything up. My best guess is something like `Usage: support [id=...]||[fields=...]` but I'd like to know the standard.

Comment: They are not optional. `<id=|fields=>`.

Comment: Except last I knew `|` implies either, but not both, right..?

Comment: I would do something like this: `<[id=…] [fields=…]>`. Both can happen, and though neither _must_ happen, there is an implication that something is required.

Comment: The easiest way around this is to make both optional, in one of two ways: (a) provide a default action for the no argument case or (b) print an error message and exit. As far as I can tell, the [POSIX Utility Conventions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html) do not have a way to express the "one or more of the following set, but at most one of each" requirement. You could also imitate [dd](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dd.html), and just call it `field_id` which you explain in the details.

Answer (score 3):

POSIX doesn't have anything to say about how to document commands, nor does any standard that I know.

A common convention is to list two separate command lines, one with `id`, one with `fields`.

```
support id=… [OPTION…]
support fields=… [OPTION…]
```

Alternatively, you can use `{id|fields}` to indicate that either can be specified (but not both). This is useful when the rest of the command line would be the same, to avoid repeating said rest. On the other hand, it is somewhat less readable.

```
support {id=NAME|fields=FIELD1,FIELD2} [OPTION]…
```

Example: the `cpio` man page under [FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=cpio&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD+10.0-RELEASE), [Solaris](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=cpio&sektion=1&manpath=SunOS+5.10), [Linux](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=cpio&sektion=1&manpath=Red+Hat+Linux%2Fi386+9) use different lines for the different modes (indicated by the choice between `-i`, `-o` and `-p`). So does [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xcu/cpio.html) itself. The Linux man page uses `{-i|--extract}` to indicate that either `-i` or `--extract` can be used; I find the use of braces without alternatives in the FreeBSD man page strange.

Comment: Firstly, http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html  and secondly, they CAN do both.. Read the question or get out.

Comment: @ChristopherWirt That's the notation used *by* the POSIX specification, not a notation that's necessarily supposed to be used in the documentation of compliant products. The spec itself uses the multiple-line notation in [pax](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/pax.html) (which is similar to my cpio example, being a newer interface for a tool with a similar purpose). P.S. [Be nice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) or get out.

Comment: @Giles, you still didn't answer the question at all. Its not too hard to show an either/or, but in my case they can have both of them