# Interactive command usage reference: do you generally have that on Unix?

Tags: posix, options, documentation, qnx

The question of why some commands rely on `manpages` whereas others rely on something like the `--help` flag for providing command usage reference [is not new](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1832/44370). There is usually a difference in scope between *documentation* for a command and a *command usage synopsis*. The latter is often a subset of the former. But even when most commands and utilities have manpages for instance, there exists differences in their formatting of the synopsis section which have very practical implications when trying to [extract](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/137076/44370) such information. In other cases one might find clues with the `strings` utility when a command has seemingly no documentation.

I was interested with the commands I have on this *QNX* platform and discovered the [`use`](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0_sp1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.neutrino_utilities%2Fu%2Fuse.html) command<sup>1</sup> to display usage information. As explained in [`usemsg`](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0_sp1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.neutrino_utilities%2Fu%2Fusemsg.html), the framework involves setting a standard usage record in the utilities source and once compiled this can be accessed with the `use` command and you can also wrap the native functionality etc. It is quite convenient as I could simply do

```
use -d dir >>file
```

on `/base` and `/proc/boot` to extract all the usage for all the commands on the system basically.

So I then briefly looked at the source for [GNU coreutils ls](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob;f=src/ls.c#l4774) and [FreeBSD ls](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/stable/10/bin/ls/ls.c?view=markup) to see if they did something like that and the former puts usage information in some *usage* named *function*(for `--help` I guess) while the latter doesn't seem to put it anywhere at all(?).

---

- Is this sort of solution(`use`) typical of what you find with *commercial Unix* to present command usage reference interactively?
- Does POSIX/SUS recommend or suggest anything about presenting/implementing command usage reference in commands(as opposed to specifying [notation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap12.html) for [shell utilities](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/132573/44370))?

---

<sup>1.`use` command:</sup>

```
use
Print a usage message (QNX Neutrino)

Syntax:
use [-aeis] [-d directory] [-f filelist] files

Options:
-a
    Extract all usage information from the load module in its source form, suitable for piping into usemsg. 
-d directory
    Recursively display information for all files under directory. 
-e
    Include only ELF files. 
-f filelist
    Read a list of files, one per line, from the specified filelist file, and display information for each. 
-i
    Display build properties about a load module. 
-s
    Display the version numbers of the source used in the executable. 
files
    One or more executable load modules or shell scripts that contain usage messages.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Commercial unices generally present usage information only in man pages. Having the command itself display usage information is not a traditional Unix feature (except for displaying the list of supported options, but without any explanation, on a usage error). POSIX and its relatives don't talk about anything like this.

Having a `--help` option that displays a usage summary (typically a list of options, one per line, with a ~60 characters max description for each option) is a [GNU standard](http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html#g_t_002d_002dhelp). As far as I know, this convention was initiated by the GNU project, as part of the double-dash convention for multi-letter option names. There are other utilities, such as X11 utilities, that use multi-letter option names with a single dash and support `-help`; I don't know which one came first.

The `use` command is a QNX thing.

Comment: So we've been spoiled with the extra GNU features on user-friendly Linux and surprisingly here with QNX! They had the plus sign before for the long options. I had not distinguished `--help` vs. displaying options on errors i.e. sometimes I enter `--help` but it's because a command may not understand the option that it lists them. I cannot do +2. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You refer to the GNU tools in your example. These are available on Linux, and many other platforms, and are somewhat unusual in terms of documentation.

The GNU tools, actually **seem** to have **three levels** of increasingly detailed interactive reference:

`--help` as a common command option - a short usage **summary**,
`man` - the classic man pages, a **"quick reference"**, and
`info` - a more detailed, GNU-speciffic manual - the full, **official documentation**.

Often, one just uses the man page as the defauls documentation - even when knowing thay "they say" the GNU info documentation is more detailed and official.

It will be varry a little based on preferences, but I think the following usage pattern is pretty common:

- using `man foo` by **default**,

  - with an explanation of all options
  - sometimes feels a little terse, but good enough
- use `foo --help` sometimes, for **small** questions, as being unsure about an option name,

  - with a short summary in compact layout
- and use `info foo`... almost **never**.

  - which would probably provide some more context details, and links to other commands
  - but nobody can use the emacs-style info browser UI, so we'll not find out exactly.
- and otherwise network based documentation,

  - like if the man page was too terse.

**There is, however, one catch:**

For the most often used commands, from the **package `coreutils`**, like `ls`, `cp`, `mkdir`, `csplit` and many more,

**the man page `man foo` contains exactly the same information as `foo --help`.** <sup>(1)</sup>

That means the **'real documentation'**, in fact, not in the man pages - as we thought...
It is actually in the **GNU info** files we **did not read**!

Now, looking at both `man` page and (the lower part of) `--help`, it's hard to notice that the content is the same, because the man page looks so "more detailed".
It's because the difference in text layout density is very large between the two variants. Extremely compressed in `--help`, compared to extremely relaxed spacing in `man`.

**Compare for yourself, it's impressive:**

`ls --help | less`

`man ls | less`

`info --subnodes ls | less`

(The option `--subnodes` renders the page lineary, for comparison. In itself, `info` shows hypertext, linked between documents similar to HTML. The `man` command includes `less` to force non-colored output for easier comparison.)

---

*Some related hints:*

There are more comfortable alternatives to the default info viewer `info`, like - for the terminal - `pinfo`, or - for the GUI -  `konqueror`. Example use like this:
`pinfo ls` or `konqueror info:ls` or using `info:ls` in the url bar of `konqueror`.

As a **special case**, the documentation of the **internal commands** of GNU `bash`,
which are called **shell builtins**, can be accessed with the `help` command.
For example, on the command line of `bash`, try
`help cd`

---

<sub>1) Fortunately, @PádraigBrady pointed that out in his answer</sub>

Comment: +1 `wc` puts it into perspective i.e. what's required to use a command vs. a full text vs. a text which expands on the features...Thanks!

Comment: It might also be useful to include something like a 3.5 - GNU Emacs provides support for Emacs specific `info` extensions like the colorization added by their source-highlight libraries and contextually aware menus and expandable content. At least, that's what my boring monochrome `info info` tells me as I read it in frustration.

Comment: It's generated directly from the output of `--help` after compiling, with `help2man`. See [this](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/man/help2man)...

Comment: @illuminÉ Thanks, interesting. I should make another question from all that, to not hide the interesting parts down here ;) And, btw, I like you style of making your statements and citing your sources.

Answer (score 2):

Note GNU coreutils man pages are generated from $cmd --help

Also note that bash builtins at least don't support --help.
There you need to use `help umask` for example.
Now POSIX allows, and ksh at least uses `umask --help`.
It was proposed recently that bash might also accept this syntax

Comment: Thanks, I see... at first, I did not think that is the case at least with `ls` - but after a closer look, that's right, the `man` page and the `--help` output **actually contain the same text!** Just in either light or compressed layout. So, my numbers just were invalidated... let's see... ;)

Comment: The sections "author", "copyright" and "see also" are generated by the manpage template system - not really content.  The interesting point is, that not `man ls` was used to write `ls --help`, but the other way around. The whole nice manpage, feeling like "some real piece of documentattion", is exactly the same as the usage message of the command. As you can see in my answer, I did not expect that!

Comment: @VolkerSiegel I now [see](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/man) what you mean with the command.x files in the _coreutils_ source tree. Many seem to be build by leveraging the content from the usage() in the .c files or elsewhere. It is not something static. I did not know this either! Thanks for explaining!